# Pb with an item creation containing a lookup field on Sharepoint 2013

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, lookup

I'm a beginner on JavaScript, and I've spent hours on a feature I try to implement on SharePoint 2013. This site already helped me a lot as I found a lot of answers and tips. But now, I'm stuck.

I have a page containing a List WebPart (the list contains actions).
I want people to select items in this list and declare their contributions to the selected actions.

To do that:
- I've created another List called 'Contributions' having a Lookup field towards the 'Actions' list.
- On the Page, I've added a Snippet with a button in order to trigger the code.
Here is the code:

```
<html>
<button id="ContributeBtn" onclick=CreateContributions()>I contribute</button>
</html>

<script>

// Initialisations

var siteUrl = 'https://communities.intra.corp/sites/Empowering';
var clientContext= new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();

// The list containing the Lookup
var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Contributions');

// The 'target' list
var oListActions =clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('5minutesActions');

var selectedItems;




function CreateContributions() {

// Load of the Ids of the selected items of the 'List' web part
var key;
selectedItems=SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(ctx);
clientContext.load(oListActions , 'Id');  //tell SharePoint to load List Id property
for (key in selectedItems) {
  clientContext.load(oListActions.getItemById(Number(selectedItems[key].id)), 'Id'); 
};

clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onIdLoaded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onIdLoadFailed));
}

function onIdLoaded(sender, args) {

// Creation of a List Item in 'Contributions' list for each selected item in the 'Task list' web part

var key;
for (key in selectedItems) {

  // Creation of a List item in the 'Contributions' list

  var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
  this.oListItem= oList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);

  // Definition of the lookup value
  var lkfieldsomthing = new SP.FieldLookupValue();
  lkfieldsomthing.set_lookupId(oListActions.getItemById(Number(selectedItems[key].id)).get_id());

  oListItem.set_item("Action", lkfieldsomthing);
  oListItem.set_item("Title", "Test");
  oListItem.update();
  clientContext.load(oListItem);

  clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
  };

}
function onIdLoadFailed(sender, args) {

    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}

function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
    alert("Success");
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {

    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}


</script>
```

My problem:
The last asynchronous query returns an error, and I have the following message: "Request failed. Column 'Action' does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user. /sites/Empowering/Lists/Contributions undefined.".

I have the feeling I'm close but I can't see where the problem is. I guess it is quite obvious for an expert eye!

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: To start with the obvious question, based on the error message... Are you certain that there is a column on your "Contributions" list with an *internal* name of "Action"?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. So, yes, I've checked several times and did it again right now.
I had chosen to choose another 'Content Type', where the 'Title' is optional. I don't know if it can affect the result!

Comment: Well... Indeed it affects the results. I've deleted the 'Contributions' List and made it from scratch and it works.
There is still a bit of mystery but I can live with that.

Comment: pluz1 gud questonzz